# Atom and React Native Aligning <View> etc tags

Tags: react-native, atom-editor

Hi is there a easy way or package to see the matching   tags? Right now i'm manually aligning them but it gets messy when its long. I end up collapsing the code which is quite manual.

How are you guys doing it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [Prettier](https://atom.io/packages/prettier-atom) extension to solve your issue.

I strongly recommend you to change to VSCode and install React Native Snippet and React Native Tools extensions. It will make your experience developing in react-native better.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and ended using [prettier-atom](https://atom.io/packages/prettier-atom)